# Cleanup huge text file containing domain

Tags: powershell, grep, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a database that contains a log of domains listed in the following matter:

```
.youtube.com
.ziprecruiter.com
0.etsystatic.com
0.sparkpost.com
00.mail.ne1.yahoo.com
00072e01.pphosted.com
00111b01.pphosted.com
001d4f01.pphosted.com
011.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
1.amazonaws.com
```

How would I go about cleaning them up using powershell or grep, though I rather use powershell, so that they contain only the root domain with the .com extension and remove whatever word and . is before that.

I'm thinking best way to do is is a query that looks for dots from right to left and removes the second dot and whatever comes after it. For example 1.amazonaws.com here we remove the second dot from the right and whatever is after it?
i.e.

```
youtube.com
ziprecruiter.com
etsystatic.com
yahoo.com
pphosted.com
amazonaws.com
```

Comment: it looks like you could split on the dots, take the last two items in the resulting array, and `-join` them with a dot. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey - You should have proposed that as an Answer; that's what RoadRunner is doing.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - yep, it seems i misjudged the significance of the idea. [*grin*] oh, well ... some one took the time that i didn't ... [*grin*] ///// on second thot, my method is different enuf to seem worth demoing. thank you for the heads-up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read each line into an array of strings with [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7), Split on `"."` using [`Split()`](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html), get the last two items with `[-2,-1]`, then join the array back up using [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7). We can then retrieve unique items using `-Unique` from [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7).

```
Get-Content -Path .\database_export.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Split('.')[-2,-1] -join '.'
} | Select-Object -Unique
```

Or using `Select-Object -Last 2` to fetch the last two items, then piping to [`Join-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string?view=powershell-7).

```
Get-Content -Path .\database_export.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Split('.') | Select-Object -Last 2 | Join-String -Separator '.'
} | Select-Object -Unique
```

**Output:**

```
youtube.com
ziprecruiter.com
etsystatic.com
sparkpost.com
yahoo.com
pphosted.com
amazonaws.com
```

Comment: the only thing i would certainly change in your code is the use of double quotes. there have been more than a few posts where the ultimate problem seemed to be the use of double quotes when singletons would have avoided unexpected variable expansion. i try to always use single quotes unless there is a _need_ for doubles.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Great point. I have updated the code to only use single quotes. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: My bad, it actually works :) I forgot to add a command to save it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `String.Trim()` method to clean leading and trailing dots, then use the regex `-replace` operator to remove everything but the top- and second-level domain name:

```
$strings = Get-Content database_export.txt

@($strings |ForEach-Object Trim '.') -replace '.*?(\w+\.\w+)$','$1' |Sort-Object -Unique
```

Answer (score 1):

here is yet another method. [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates an array of strings to work with
  when ready to do this for real, remove the entire `#region/#endregion` section and use `Get-Content` to load the file.
- iterates thru the `$InStuff` collection of strings
- splits the current item on the dots
- grabs the last two items in the resulting array
- joins them with a dot
- outputs the new string to the `$Results` collection
- shows that on screen

the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
.youtube.com
.ziprecruiter.com
0.etsystatic.com
0.sparkpost.com
00.mail.ne1.yahoo.com
00072e01.pphosted.com
00111b01.pphosted.com
001d4f01.pphosted.com
011.mail.bf1.yahoo.com
1.amazonaws.com
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a text file

$Results = foreach ($IS_Item in $InStuff)
    {
    $IS_Item.Split('.')[-2, -1] -join '.'
    }

$Results
```

output ...

```
youtube.com
ziprecruiter.com
etsystatic.com
sparkpost.com
yahoo.com
pphosted.com
pphosted.com
pphosted.com
yahoo.com
amazonaws.com
```

please note that this code expects the strings to be more-or-less-valid URLs. i can think of invalid ones that end with a dot ... and those would fail. if you need to deal with such, add the needed validation code.

another idea ... if the file is large [tens of thousands of strings], you may want to use the `ForEach-Object` pipeline cmdlet [as shown by `RoadRunner`] to save RAM at the expense of speed.

Comment: Actually, I'm given to understand that a terminal dot may in fact be valid, but has null effect - that is, if it's permitted, `example.com` and `example.com.` are considered equivalent. You can address that if you choose by `$IS_Item.Trim('.').Split('.')[-2,-1] -join '.'`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - wow! i was sure that was invalid. [*grin*] still, it will blow that code out the wall if it aint dealt with. if the OP needs, it i hope he/she asks ...